# problems with a null value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach, null

I have a foreach loop to add the values from an array into a codeigniter where function. When I pass a value with content into this loop, it does not alter. However, when a null value goes in, it comes out with the value of the item before it in the array.

Here is the code:

```
if(is_null($data['psc_opt_5'])){ echo "null"; }else{ echo $data['psc_opt_5']; }
foreach($data as $field => $value)
{

    if(!is_null($value))
    {

        $this->db->where($field, $value);

    }
    else
    {

        $this->db->where($field." IS NULL");

    }

}

if(is_null($data['psc_opt_5'])){ echo "null"; }else{ echo $data['psc_opt_5']; }
```

The array holds psc_opt_1 - psc_opt_5.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

An the first if statement proves that psc_opt_5 is null before the loop and here are the arrays I'm testing with:

> Array
>   (
>       [psc_opt_1] => 1
>       [psc_opt_2] => 2
>       [psc_opt_3] => 3
>       [psc_opt_4] => 4
>       [psc_opt_5] => 
>   )
>
> Array
>   (
>       [psc_opt_1] => 5
>       [psc_opt_2] => 2
>       [psc_opt_3] => 3
>       [psc_opt_4] => 4
>       [psc_opt_5] => 
>   )
>
> Array
>   (
>       [psc_opt_1] => 7
>       [psc_opt_2] => 2
>       [psc_opt_3] => 3
>       [psc_opt_4] => 4
>       [psc_opt_5] => 
>   )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the foreach doesn't like the null value being passed into it, so it retains the value of the previous cycle. I found that if I add the ampersamp as below, it passes the null value through:

```
foreach($data as $field => &$value)
{



}
```

Comment: Take a look at my edited code, compare the results from your array and mine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a NULL vs. Empty problem.
NULL is a non value while ' ' is a empty string with 0 characters.

Edited code:

```
<?php
$data = array (
    "psc_opt_1" => '1',
    "psc_opt_2" => '2',
    "psc_opt_3" => '3',
    "psc_opt_4" => '4',
    "psc_opt_5" => '',          
);


foreach($data as $field => $value)
{

 echo 'Now processing: '.$field.' | ';

    if(!is_null($value) && !empty($value))
    {
        echo $field.' has value of: '.$value;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $field.' is empty of NULL';
    }
    echo '</br>';

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't affect it, why could it be pulling the previous value in? Btw, I have an if statement above the foreach loop that sets the value to null, but I didn't think that was relevant as the first if proves the value is null before I go into the loop